# Nest.js get current request from anywhere in code

Tags: javascript, typescript, express, nestjs

I need to access request object from a service deep down in the call chain. I don't want to pass it through an argument, because that would be a lot of changes.

I've tried doing it using a request-scoped provider:

```
@Injectable({ scope: Scope.REQUEST })
export class FetcherService {
  constructor(
    private defaultProductFetcher: DefaultProductFetcher,
    private loopbackFetcher: LoopbackFetcher,
    @Inject(REQUEST) private readonly request: Request,
  ) {}

  // ...use this.request here for proxying headers to other services
}
```

But this, for some unknown reason, prevents **all** services in my application from calling `onModuleInit` and because of this application doesn't work properly.

1. Why are all `onModuleInit` methods affected by this?
2. Is there a better way of getting request information?

Comment: I guess you should create interceptor & service for that. Inside interceptor you can put request into service and share this data in any places of your app via service.

Answer (score 1):

as stated in the docs [here](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/lifecycle-events#lifecycle-events-1):

> The lifecycle hooks listed above are not triggered for request-scoped classes. Request-scoped classes are not tied to the application lifecycle and their lifespan is unpredictable. They are exclusively created for each request and automatically garbage-collected after the response is sent.

If you're using node16 you could use the [`nestjs-cls`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nestjs-cls) instead.